# List condition to get true or false in new list

Tags: python

I have my list:

```
>>> labels = ['setosa', 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'virginica']
```

I want to create a new list, with the same amount of elements with `True` on `'setosa'` index, and `False` elsewhere.

I have tried like this

```
>>> b = 'setosa' in labels
>>> b
True
```

I want a list with 5 elements:

```
[True, True, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
lst = [label == "setosa" for label in labels]
```

Comment: because it's shorter and everyone who sees it, gives a vote

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**`map`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), which in Python 2 returns a `list`:

```
>>> labels = ['setosa', 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'versicolor', 'virginica']
>>> map('setosa'.__eq__, labels)
[True, True, False, False, False]
```

In Python 3 if you *need* a list:

```
>>> list(map('setosa'.__eq__, labels))
[True, True, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could to use the `.append()` function:

```
new_list = []

for element in labels: new_list.append('setosa' == element)
```

Comment: sorry @PeterWood